# Why does vue emit propagate to parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue. I have a child component like below. I added a validator via the 'emits' property and I assumed that if the validator fails then the parent event handler doesn't get called but it does. I also don't see a way to validate the input in the parent or in the child. I know I could add a method in the child component that I assign to the emit property and check it in the child and then only call $emit' if it returns true but it seems backwards. I'm sure I'm missing the point here, someone please clarify because it seems to me that the 'emits' property validator is only for debugging purposes and doesn't actually modify the app behavior, just throws a console warning. To me that is a bug waiting to happen. Is there some vue config setting that I need to change to enable the behavior I was expecting? What am I missing? (btw, when I run `npm show vue version` I get 3.2.45 if that would matter.

The console showing that the parent handler was called.

[image: console log]

**Child Component:**

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      age: null,
    };
  },
  emits: {
    "new-user": function (obj) {
        return obj && typeof obj.username == 'string' && typeof obj.age == 'number';
    },
  },
  methods: {
    newUser() {
        const output = { username: this.username, age: this.age };
        this.$emit("new-user", output);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The parent component:

```html
<template>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <user-data @new-user="newUser"></user-data>
</template>    
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  methods: {
    newUser(val) {
      console.log('emitted newUser',val)          
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a function to `emits` will not affect whether the event is emitted, it is only meant for validation. See [docs here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events)

though I see that it's not very clear from the docs:

> ```js
> export default {
>  emits: {
>    submit(payload) {
>      // return `true` or `false` to indicate
>      // validation pass / fail
>    }
>  }
> }
> ```

To make the emit conditional you could use

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      age: null,
    };
  },
  emits: ["new-user"],
  methods: {
    newUser() {
      if (typeof this.username == 'string' && typeof this.age == 'number'){
        const output = { username: this.username, age: this.age };
        this.$emit("new-user", output);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It would be nice for there to be a setting in vue to block emits if the validation fails. It can be true so it doesn't break current builds but allow us to stop propagation if we as the programmer said it wasn't valid. I can't even see a way as the receiver to verify if the value is valid. Only the emitter knows that it failed, the receiver has no idea if it passed/failed. I don't understand that logic

Comment: The condition that's in your emits definition could be used as to determine whether to `$emit` within your `newUser` method. (see example in updated answer) I don't really see what the value would be to abstract that through another layer.

Answer (score 1):

You're spot on.

Emit validation only shows a console warning. It is not a mechanism to not emit something.

Similar to prop validation, its primary use is for development. Very useful for large teams or if you're making a component library.